# File path in FileUpload widget of GWT in IE-8 is EDITABLE

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, file-upload, uibinder

I am using "FileUpload" widget of GWT and it is working perfectly fine with one issue though.

In Internet Explorer version 8, the textfield which is beside Browse button, remains enabled; means user can enter any characters in it (e.g. a non-existent file path or name). Then if user clicks upload then nothing happens.

[image]

So, I was trying to somehow "disable" this textfield part or avoid keydown events inside it. But I was not able to do that.

Comment: That is how an HTML file input works in IE8

Comment: Even though dummy text is entered in textbox.U can browse and upload a file .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do so much with the native input-file, even it is almost impossible to style it. These constrains are because of historical security reasons.

What you can do, is to use your own widget to open the file browser dialog, but this needs many tweaks which are different for each browser. If you want to do that I recommend the [gwtupload](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload) widget: [DecoratedFileUpload](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/source/browse/core/src/main/java/gwtupload/client/DecoratedFileUpload.java#50). Take a look to the gwtupload [demo](http://gwtupload.alcala.org/gupld/).